# How can I use apacite to write the source of a figure?

Tags: apacite

I would like to add my source + references to my figures in the APA style.

I am not sure if apacite is the correct package but I would like to have a clickable line under my figures saying: 'source: some apa style source'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. There's no difference in using `apacite` to add citations to captions for figures than for using citations anywhere else in the text. If you've tried something that didn't work, turn it into a small example document that shows the problem and we can help you with that. If you're asking about APA style citations in general see [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793)

Comment: Also see [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812) for examples of using the two main implementations of strict APA style.