# \citeA from apacite is doing nothing, but why?

Tags: apacite

I am new to referencing with LaTeX and I am trying to finde the best way to put the source under my figure. From the apacite docs the command \citeA looked good but it does no do anything, at least wrapped in a figure.

Basically I am trying to remove the parentheses from the default cite command. My bibtex is fine.

Comment: Could you explain what you want the input to be and what you expect the output to look like? The `\citeA` command is intended to be used to cite a paper from your own bibliography (i.e., an entry from your `.bib` file). However, you seem to want a full citation (with author, journal, pages, year, publisher etc) to appear within your text (and possibly repeat that reference in your reference list, but you didn't specify that). As far as I know `apacite` does not have a command for a full in-text citation. Of course you can always add the citation manually if you want.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650148/2693). Instead of asking a new question, it's more helpful to edit the original question to clarify what you're asking. In particular, in neither question is it very clear what you are actually seeking, and it would be most helpful to add a small compilable example document that shows what you're doing along with a description of what output you want.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still not very clear. APA citation style has two forms: Author (Year) or (Author, Year), i.e., depending on whether the citation is inside parentheses or part of the text. Both are possible with `apacite`. Is what you want the second one?

Comment: Plus if you use `apacite` `\citeA` should work, so it would really help if you could show us the code you have tried in a small example document (with as little excess code as possible) that reproduces how it did not work for you.